# How to start grunt server in Jenkins correct

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I have job in Jenkins where i build web app and start it via command:
`grunt server`
but when i do this build in Jenkins dont finishing because server still running in prompt:

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on localhost:80.
Running "open:server" (open) task
Running "watch" task
```

So, how can i run grunt server in Jenkins in order to server still run but build finished successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grunt server` command usually opens a local server via node, that you can do testing on. If you used yeoman or other you want the Jenkins to run the `grunt build` command.

The problem is the `watch` task, it will keep running looking for file changes, and automatically update the webpage via live-reload. It's quite smart for development, but not intended for a build server.

Comment: But with grunt build the server won't start. I tried Express but the same thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by sending process to the background via command  :
`grunt server &`
so jenkins finished build as succesful

Comment: And then, how do you shut it down on the next build, so you can start it again once the build is done?

Answer (score 0):

I still do have this problem and Jenkins doesn't build successfully with any of these commands:

```
grunt serve &
nohup grunt serve
nohup grunt serve > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But to kill process I execute this command before copying new files, `npm install`, etc.

```
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep grunt | awk '{print $2}')
```