# Can not access webserver started by running gruntscript in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, webserver

I am trying to set up a webserver using jenkins but I am failing misserably. 
I have a gruntfile which creates a webserver on

> hostname: '0.0.0.0'
>
> port: 8000

When running it locally on my computer, this works perfectly. Now I have to add this job to jenkins. The job I run is an infinite job so I run it in the background like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430364/how-to-start-grunt-server-in-jenkins-correct). Except for the fact that I am working with a windows server

When I run the gruntscript through jenkins, I get the following output:
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:8000

But when I go to http://%jenkinsserver%:8000 I don't get anything. I am sure there is something running on that port. At first I thought there were some issues with the firewall, but after accessing the server directly, I still could not find the webpage.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Could you please run `lsof -i :8000` on jenkins node? Is it outputing anything? Another thing is 0.0.0.0 shouldn't be the right host in case you are not using only localhost, you should used `localhost` then.